# Pandas: Create data frame using a list of Pandas.Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to make a dataframe in pandas using a list of items

```
def my_func(data):
   i_list = []

   # Get data
   for x in range(0, 10):
      i_list.append(get_series(data, x)

   pd_i = pd.concat([{'ind_{0}'.format(i), i_list[i]} for i in range(len(i_list))])
```

In this case get_series() returns a pandas series, but I get this error:

> TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Realistically, I don't actually need to contact. What I have is a list of pandas series objects and an additional pandas series that I want to put all into the same data frame. Each of these series will have the same index as `data.index`, the only difference is that I want one of the columns to have a specific name.

Is there a way to dynamically make a pandas dataframe using a list of series or array object who all have the same index?

Comment: you're trying to concat sets, try concatting dicts

Answer (score 0):

To create a dataframe from a list of series with the same index, pass the series to `pd.concat` with `axis=1`:

```
series_list = [series1, series2, series3]
result_df = pd.concat(series_list, axis=1)
```